# how to configure vim commands to windows style?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

My job involves working on Windows, *ix and with variety of IDE's like Eclipse, Visual Studio. Sometimes I really don't want to open Eclipse for little editing so I would prefer simple text editor like Vim, but the keys for the commands are horrible to me, I would like to setup Vim command keys to simple and modern style.

Can someone guide me how to configure Vim commands to simple keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for copy paste (through clipboard) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for selecting text.

Comment: Key rebinding? I do believe you're thinking of emacs ;)

Comment: Try taking the time to learn some of the most common Vim commands. While the learning curve starts off a bit steep, it is a very powerful and nice to use editor once you've learned the basics.

Comment: @hammer, i dont think its a good idea to learn Esc+V + rightArrow(s) then 'd' and 'p' to select text than simple Shift + RightArrow  and Ctrl_c and Ctrl_v.

Comment: That's not really the commands you would use in Vim. For example, instead of using visual mode and right arrows you'd usually use a motion command, for example `d%` to cut a function call, or `da"` to cut a string literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question: [How do I configure VIM for using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> as copy paste to and from system buffer in ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/61226/how-do-i-configure-vim-for-using-ctrl-c-ctrl-v-as-copy-paste-to-and-from-system-b)

and the over all help on how to do key mapping here: [How to make a keymap](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_make_a_keymap)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the answer you're looking for, but I'm with hammar. For example the Mac version of vim has the standard Mac-style copy/paste shortcut keys "baked in" yet I use the default vim keybindings now, since, like yourself, I hop about Linux/Windows/Mac, and having the same vim keyboard shortcuts.

Conversely, you'll find managing your personalized, if unorthodox, key bindings more onerous than simply "going vim."

I presume you've "worked" the vimtutor?

Comment: I also use Vim/gvim on Mac, Windows and Linux. It's awesome to use the same configuration on all platforms with the same fonts and schemes and plugins. It's so powerful and so much more convenient using vim's normal keypresses instead of trying to make it fit Windows.